# Comparing the contents of 2 .nsm (naming standards) files

Tags: naming-convention, erwin

I have 2 naming standards files from ERwin (.nsm extension), and I want to compare them to see if they contain the same rules. Is there some sort of automated way to check this?

If there isn't a way to compare the two within ERwin itself, is there a way to convert the 2 files into a more 'standard' file type (i.e. an Excel file), and then compare the files that way? I'm coming from a programming perspective (mostly Java), and from what I've seen it wouldn't be that hard to write a program that compares 2 Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Export both files, see [How do I open an ERwin Naming Standards file (.nsm) in Excel?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104196/how-do-i-open-an-erwin-naming-standards-file-nsm-in-excel)

Use a file compare tool to compare the contents.

If you decide to write a program yourself, follow the advice in this Stack Overflow answer:

[Comparing the contents of 2 excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779805/3503801)